# Multilevel submenu codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have to extend an existing menu to a multilevel one. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it so I'm hoping somebody can help me out.

1. First I've added another table in the database with the name parent_id.
2. Then I'd like to see if this column is filled out, so greater than > 0.
3. And then of course, check to see if id == parent_id.

If so, I'd like to display my submenu on hover of the parent item.

My current menu is a multi lang menu.

This is my current model:

```
var $default_order_by = array('position');

function findView($page)
{
    $language = $this->config->item('language');
    $p = new Page();
    $p->where('url_' . $language, $page)->get();
    return $p->view;
}

function findPageMenu($page)
{
    $language = $this->config->item('language');
    $p = new Page();
    $p->where('url_' . $language, $page)->get();
    return $p->menu;
}

function findAllByView()
{
    $pages = new Page();
    $result = array();
    foreach ($pages->get() as $page)
        $result[$page->view] = $page;

    return $result;
}

function getMenu()
{
    $pages = new Page();
    if ($this->session->userdata('is_admin'))
        return $pages->where('position >', 0)->get();
    else
        return $pages->where('position >', 0)->where('admin', 0)->get();
}

function getUrlByView($view)
{
    $page = new Page();
    $page->where('view', $view)->get();
    $language = $this->config->item('language');
    return $page->{'url_' . $language};
}
```

And this is my view:

```
   <ul class="primary-nav">
    <?php foreach($menu as $page): ?>
     <li class="primary-nav__item">
        <a class="primary-nav__link" <?php if ($page_menu == $page->view): ?>class="active" <?php endif; ?>href="<?php echo base_url() . $this->config->item('language_abbr') . '/' . $page->{'url_' . $this->config->item('language')}; ?>"> 
            <?php echo mb_strtoupper($page->{'title_' . $this->config->item('language')}, 'UTF-8'); ?>
        </a>
    </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
function getSubMenu()
{
      if ($this->session->userdata('is_admin'))
        return $pages->where('position >', 0 && 'parent_id >', 0)->get();
    else
        // return $pages->where('position >', 0 && 'parent_id >', 0)->get();
        echo '<h1> yay </h1>';
}
```

(ignore the yay, lol) But this obviously doesn't even begin to cut it.

Comment: pls show your page method

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion**: You can add the "parent_id" in the same table. If there is a parent then fill it with parent id or with 0.

**Answer**: Get your data as a one dimentional array with all the rows with parent id. Then use the below function to create a multi dimensional array with parent and child.

```
function formatTree($tree, $parent = NULL) {
    $treeArray = array();
    foreach ($tree as $item) {
        if ($item['menu_parent'] == 0) {
            $treeArray[$item['menu_id']] = $item;
        }
        else {
            $treeArray[$item['menu_parent']]['sub'][] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $treeArray;
}
```

Now use the below function to make an intended ul-li list of parent-child menu

```
function buildMenu($menu_array, $is_sub = FALSE) {
    $attr = (!$is_sub) ? ' class="sidebar-menu"' : ' class="treeview-menu"';
    $menu = "<ul>"; // Open the menu container
    foreach ($menu_array as $id => $properties) {
        if (!isset($properties['sub'])) {
            $is_sub = TRUE;
        }
        elseif (empty($properties['sub'])) {
            $is_sub = TRUE;
        }
        foreach ($properties as $key => $val) {
            if (is_array($val) && !empty($val)) {
                $sub = $this -> buildMenu($val, TRUE);
            }
            else {
                $sub = NULL;
                $$key = $val;
            }
        }
        if ($properties['menu_url']) {
            $url = $properties['menu_url'];
        }
        $menu .= "<li>" . $menu_name . "</li>";
        unset($url, $menu_name, $sub);
    }
    return $menu . "</ul>";
}
```

I am using this in my application. The array structure of menu data should be

```
array(
  [0] => array(
    'menu_name' => 'name',
    'menu_url' => 'url',
    'menu_id' => 'id',
    'menu_parent' => 'parent id'
  ),
 [1] => array(
    'menu_name' => 'name',
    'menu_url' => 'url',
    'menu_id' => 'id',
    'menu_parent' => 'parent id'
 )
)
```